# Run scripts after oem firstboot

Tags: oem

I have installed ubuntu using the oem-install.  I was able to add packages, install software and do updates that then show up appropriately on first boot after the user sets up the machine and their account.  What I need to do is copy some files and directories to the users home directory AFTER their /home/ directory is created.  How can I do this?  Preferably with the oem install feature itself but I'm open to other ideas as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
/etc/skel
```

Put what you want to be in the user's home directory in /etc/skel. Browse the internet for */etc/skel* and you will find several helpful links, for example

[www.linfo.org/etc_skel.html](http://www.linfo.org/etc_skel.html)

Answer (score 0):

/etc/skel will always build ANY new user's home directory.

Make sure that you are not going crazy with files. I tried to setup phoronix-test-suite for my OEM user in this manner, but I forgot that those files get created under EVERY user's home directory. Took me 20 minutes to figure out why I was losing almost 5GB of data after the install (3 users with 1.7GB of PTS files == DOH!)